# Round to x.5 in C

Tags: c, algorithm, rounding

I like to round a floating number to nearest x.5. For example:

```
-3.64 -> -3.5

-3.12 -> -3.5

-2.90 -> -2.5

-0.45 -> -0.5

0.01  ->  0.5

7.65  ->  7.5

8.45  ->  8.5

9.63   -> 9.5
```

Is there a decent way to implement it in C? Thanks.

**NOTE:
I did NOT want to "round it to nearest half" !! Read the question and think before down vote please!!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about doing a simple `floor(x) + 0.5`? Should handle positive and negative values. If the numbers are exact integers they get rounded up to the next higher +0.5.

```
floor(0) + 0.5 = 0.5
floor(-1.2) + 0.5 = -1.5
floor(2.2) + 0.5 = 2.5
```

Like @Stephen added in the comments using `ceil(x) - 0.5` instead would result in the same values except that exact integers get rounded down to the next lowest -0.5. i.e.:

```
ceil(0) - 0.5 = -0.5
ceil(-1.2) - 0.5 = -1.5
ceil(2.2) - 0.5 = 2.5
```

Comment: And if you want exact integers to round down, use `ceil(x) - 0.5`.

Comment: I guess integer can be either rounded up or down, because an integer should have the same distance to either last x.5 or next x.5?

Comment: @Ono yeh, up to you. `floor(x) + 0.5` rounds up, `ceil(x) - 0.5` rounds down in those cases. It's easy to change if you put it in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function :

```
float nearest_x_dot_5(float x)
{
    return round(x - 0.5) + 0.5;
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66372aa3de599aaa)

Comment: This isn't quite correct; if x is a very small positive number, the result should be `0.5`, but `round(x - 0.5) + 0.5 = round(-0.5) + 0.5 = -1 + 0.5 = -0.5`.

Comment: Well it seems to work with this test using epsilon from <limits> : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd1a15c4a1300cac .

Comment: Try it with `x = 0x1.0p-100`.

Comment: Oh it gives -0.5. I supposed 0x1.0p-100 represents a positive small number ? Can you explain it ?

Comment: 0x1.0p-100 is 2^-100 in hexadecimal floating-point notation.  I.e. a tiny positive number.

Comment: Nice :D thanks for the info. I ll let this post for this non evident case. Should be interesting for readers.

Answer (score -1):

Sure! `((int)(f-0.5))+0.5` for positive numbers, you will find for negative numbers by yourself I think.

Comment: This rounds to the nearest multiple of 0.5. What the OP actually wants is to round to the nearest number ending in .5, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: @intjay -- are you sure?